# Multiple frontends, shared backend and dealing with concurrent requests attached to one session

Tags: session

Let say I have a simple architecture where sessions would be shared through a database, with multiple frontends (say F1 and F2) speaking to the same backend.

My issue is the case where both frontends would receive a request corresponding to a same session: a naive implementation would cause session to overwrite each other (I looked at django which seems to fall into that case). I could try to design the backend such as it garantees that no more than one frontend can deal with a given session, but this seems hard to do correctly, especially if I want to handle frontend failures.

I can't help but thinking that the case is pathologic in the first place (there should not be more than one request for a given session at any time), and is not worths being dealt for, but I have not much experience in web development, so maybe I am missing something. How does one usually deal with this case ?

Possible solutions that I would like to avoid:

- Sticky session: that's the solution I currently use, and is difficult to support once you have several load balancers, and more significantly goes against the spirit of load balancing in the first place.
- Putting data in cookie: for technical reasons outside my control, I cannot use cookie.

Comment: I don't understand why it should matter ? FWIW, I am using python + mysql to prototype something.

Answer (score 0):

One common solution is known as session persistence. Whatever routes your request to the f1 or f2 ensures that as long as a session is active, the client with that session only goes to one frontend.

It is a common feature in almost all loadbalancers. For example, nginx has the ip_hash http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did not want that solution (that's the one I currently rely on, but I would like to avoid it).

Comment: Ok the alternative is to stick all the relevant session information into the cookie (or some JS data construct, in js you could compress it, etc). Then if the request comes the either f1 or f2 the session can quickly be reconstructed. This would work with reasonable session information sizes. The loadbalancer method is easier, since you have it already.

Comment: I cannot use cookie (and the session could become too big for cookie - the point is to use some AI on the sessions, which mean they would contain some more data than usual)

Comment: Ok this is becoming interesting. What I would do given those constraints is to develop a finger-print algorithm for the client. IP and another unique identifier. Then you need a back-end transaction log/queue, that the front-end will check on user requests, and update on changes. This way you will insure front-end consistency. Other then that I am curios on solutions as well.